# Storing PID of the busiest process in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm trying to store the PID of the busiest process in a variable in BASH script.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       915  1.7  0.8 319948 34088 tty7     Ssl+ May05   3:24 /usr/lib/xorg/X
root       920  0.0  0.0  15940   116 tty1     Ss+  May05   0:00 /sbin/agetty --
deego    25690  0.1  0.1  22376  4900 pts/1    Ss   02:06   0:00 bash
deego    25704  101  0.0  12536   908 pts/1    R    02:07   0:03 /bin/bash ./busy_wait
deego    25705  0.0  0.0  37364  3272 pts/1    R+   02:07   0:00 ps au
```

when I type the command:

ps au --sort=-pcpu | head -2 | tail -1

```
deego    25704 99.5  0.0  12536   908 pts/1    R    02:07   0:46 /bin/bash ./busy_wait
```

It gives me the correct sorting.

However, when I'm assigning it to a variable using awk in the script, the variable seems to always be assigned the wrong PID(always 915)

```
busyPID=$(ps au --sort=-pcpu | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: `ps au --sort=-pcpu | awk 'NR==2{print $2; exit}'`

Comment: No, just giving an empty variable unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Why not suppress the header and grab the first line?

```
busy_pid=$(ps hau --sort=-pcpu | awk '{print $2; exit}')
```

Comment: or print only pid: `ps aho pid --sort=-pcpu | awk '{print $1; exit}'`

Comment: No, these are just returning nothing, unfortunately

Comment: It worked perfectly for me.  What's the output of `ps hau --sort=-pcpu` for you?